# Rails 3 - Got "Undefined local variable or method `f' " when use ajax to execute remote javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a question on this:
I have a partial named `_return_item.html.erb`, so I want to render it repeatedly and dynamically.

```
<%= f.fields_for :return_items, return_item do |item_form| %>
  some_field_input_for_return_item
<%end%>
```

The `index.html.erb` is like this:

```
<%= form_for(@return_request) do |f| %>
  <div id="contact">
    <!-- some_field_input_for_request_contact_info -->
  </div>
  <div id="itemlist">
    <!-- This part is working-->

    <% @return_request.return_items.each do |item| %>
      <%= render :partial => "return_items/return_items", :locals => {:f => f, :return_item => item}%>
      <!-- I_want_to_append_the_partial_here -->
    <%end%>

  </div>
  <%= button_tag("Add New Item", :class=>"addItem" )%>
<%end%>

<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $( '.addItem' ).click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "return_requests/request_new_item",
        data: {
               item_num: ($( '#itemlist' ).children().length)
              },
        dataType: "script"
      })
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

The `request_new_item` controller is like this:

```
def request_new_item
  @return_item = ReturnItem.new 
end
```

and here is `request_new_item.js.erb` :

```
 $("#itemlist").append('<%= j render :partial => "return_items/return_items", :locals => {:f => f, :return_item => item } %>');
```

When I press the button `addItem`, I expect to generate a new partial, but actually, this doesn't work. The console provide an error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f5a302232b0>:0x007f5a380afea8>)
```

UPDATE:
I forgot to post the model:
`return_request.rb`:

```
class ReturnRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :return_items, :class_name=>'ReturnItem', :foreign_key=>'RMA_Nmb', :primary_key=>'RMA_Nmb'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :return_items
end
```

`return_item.rb`:

```
class ReturnItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :return_request, :class_name=>"ReturnRequest"
end
```

So, could anybody explain me how this happen, and how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.html.erb`, the variable `f` is passed into the block, but in `request_new_item.js.erb`, where can `f` come? It is really undefined in that erb.

I think the browser doesn't have to request that piece of HTML from server. Instead, it can just duplicate the existing partial and append it. To make it easy to duplicate, you can wrap the partial in `_return_item.html.erb` with a DIV. You may need to adjust some names of fields  in the partial before appending it.

The gem called "[nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)" could be a choice too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do that over the browser. How can I tell controller to generate a new item for the return request?

Comment: In your controller, you just create an object, but never save it, right? The items should be save along with the associated object.

Comment: So, you mean that I don't need to care about it, just save everything at one time with the return request?

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved this question,using some other way, as @Yanhao said. The reason it reports `undefined local variable or method f` because I put the javascript snippet outside the `form_for` block. It is certain that I can not locate `f` and `item`.
I followed @Yanhao's suggestion and use `append` which is provide by jquery to implement the dynamical effect: 
First, I put the `<script>` tag inside the `form_for` so it can locate the `f` and for the variable `item`. I just use the following code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( '.addItem' ).click(function () {

       $("#accordion").append('<%= j render :partial => "return_items/return_items", :locals => {:f => f, :return_item => @return_request.return_items.build }%>');

      return false;
    });
  });
```

this code is work perfect to me. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: This should work, but it violates "Unobtrusive JavaScript" principles. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: So, could you give me some suggestions on this? If I wanna do something like this, how to make it Unobtrusive? Thank you

Comment: The reason I asked again is because I am using JqueryUI - "accordion" to achieve the item frame. so actually, it must have 2 divs to make a item form. could you provide a simple jquery code, to clone 2 divs at one time?

Comment: Even if you don't want to use `nested_form`, you can learn something from it. `nested_form` does it this way: a hidden DIV will be created, which holds the fields for a new item, having an ID of "[assoc]_fields_blueprint". When the link for adding is clicked, it finds the hidden DIV, replaces some strings and appends the content to the form. You can check the source code of `nested_form` to see the details.